# p4java - how to move opened files to another changelist?

Tags: p4java

Say I have a file already opened in the default changelist and I want to move it to another changelist.   The Move operation allow me to specify a new changelist, but my move is ignored since the path didn't change in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

While in P4V this is called "Move to Another Changelist", the p4java name is the same as the p4 command line terminology, where this is called "reopen"ing a file.  Try: `IClient.reopenFiles()`

`client.reopenFiles(Arrays.asList(new IFileSpec[] { fileSpec }), newChanglist, null);`